# Test variable in an element

Tags: protractor

How do I test the variable inside an element's attribute?

e.g.:
HTML

```
<div id="accordion1" class="panel" is-open="item.open">
```

Protractor:

```
expect(element(by.id(accordion1)).getAttribute('is-open')).toBe(true);
```

This fails with 'item.open expected to be true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, but I don't know if this is the best answer

```
expect(element.id('accordion1').getAttribute('is-open').evaluate('item.open')).toEqual(true);
```